# How to solve multiprocessing stop working problem in Python 3.7.2 using venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

2019-01-12 Update

I reinstalled Python 3.7.1 and remade venv to get everything back to work.

But still, I am unaware of what happens in 3.7.2.

---

I have been using **multiprocessing.map_async** and .apply_async in my data processing project. It worked fine in python 3.6 until 3.7.1 but when I urgrade to 3.7.2 and recreated venv, the main process just hang indefinitely and subprocesses not working at all.

I am using **Windows10** and PyCharm Community.

I tried both the tool inside PyCharm  and 'python -m venv' to create venv, but neither worked.
I looked for documentation in python.org and found

https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-7-2-final

It says,

> "venv on Windows will now use a python.exe redirector rather than copying the actual binaries from the base environment."

I wonder if this has caused the problem.

Example codes are as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support, Pool

def test_func(x):
    y = x + 1
    return y

if __name__ == '__main__':
freeze_support()
test_data = list(range(10))
with Pool(4) as test_pool:
    for test_datum in test_data:
        apply_result = test_pool.apply_async(test_func, test_datum)
        print(apply_result.get())
```

I add a breakpoint in the last line and entered debug mode. Then I found that the **apply_result** object, which is a **multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult**, has a **_cache** attribute. Under **_cache** there is the same **multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult** but with the name of "**0 (140716767896368)**", which also has a **_cache** attribute, and on and on.

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6q5f.png)

I was desperate and tried possibly the simplest code (modified from official doc):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

It hangs still.

If I choose the system interpreter, not using venv, it works fine.

```
[1, 4, 9]
```

I would sincerely appreciate any help in solving this problem.

Comment: If worse comes to worst and a solution isn't found, you might have to revert back to using python 3.6 unless there is a new function in the latest version that you need to use

Comment: Maybe try creating the venv with the `--copies` option (e.g. `python -m venv venv --copies`)

Comment: @SPYBUG96 Yes, since I need the new dataclass feature reverting to 3.7.1 would do. Still it's better if I could fix the bug.

Comment: @SPYBUG96 Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr I tried but sadly it did not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: such a shame that I just wasted a few hours on this issue... thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, on Mac and with VS Code....

So here is my solution.

```
import joblib
from joblib import Parallel,delayed

def f(x):
    return x*x

number_of_cpu = joblib.cpu_count()
delayed_funcs = [delayed(f)(x) for x in [1,2,3]]
parallel_pool = Parallel(n_jobs=number_of_cpu,prefer="processes")
print(parallel_pool(delayed_funcs))
```

the doc is well documented anyway...